# How can I fix "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when using jQuery with mocha-jsdom?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

I'm setting up ES6 unit tests in my project and I am having some trouble making them work with libraries. I thought I'd use jQuery just as a test to try and make it work. Without libraries, the tests work.

Note that jQuery is imported into my main.js file so it is available throughout the project.

My JS file looks like this:

```
class Test {
  constructor(options) {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    $('.test-div').addClass('test');
  }

  sayHello() {
    return 'hello world!';
  }
}

export default Test;
```

And the test looks like this:

```
import jsdom from 'mocha-jsdom';
import chai from 'chai';
import Test from './test';

chai.should();

describe('Frequency', () => {

  var $;
  jsdom();

  before(() => {
    $ = require('jquery');
  })

  it('should output hello world', () => {
      const test = new Test();
      test.sayHello().should.equal('hello world!');
  });

});
```

If I remove the `init()` function, the test works. However, the before function doesn't seem to import jQuery for the test. The error I receive in the console is as follows:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
  at Frequency.init
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$` is defined for the file that exports `Test`? Note that your spec is not requiring `main.js`, it's only requiring `./test` therefore your `./test` file should also import jquery i.e. `import $ from 'jquery'` in `./test`

Comment: Thanks for the response @MauricioPoppe - I imported `main.js` in and it's now complaining about things like picturefill and then window not being defined. Do i have to attach my jspm.config file to it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and got it to work by modifying the `before` hook to:

```
before(() => {
  $ = require('jquery');
  global.$ = $;
});
```

If you read [`mocha-jsdom`](https://github.com/rstacruz/mocha-jsdom)'s documentation you'll see that it puts in the global space symbols like `window` and `document`. When you load `jquery`, it finds `window` and adds itself as `window.$`. In a browser, this *also* makes `$` visible in the global space because `window` *is* the global space. In Node, however, the global space is `global`, and so you have to put `$` in it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to answer this @Louis - I'm still getting the error unfortunately. 

Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' at Context.<anonymous> (test.spec.js:13:9)
      at Object.done (node_modules/mocha-jsdom/index.js:70:7)
      at node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:249:18. Can I ask what you are running on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare global variables in a custom setup.js:

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "unit": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config webpack.test.js  test/unit/*.spec.js --require test/setup.js"
 },
```

or if you don't use webpack:

```
"scripts": {
     "unit": "mocha test/unit/*.spec.js --require test/setup.js"
},
```

test/setup.js:

```
let jsdom = require('jsdom-global')();
let jQuery = require("jquery");

global.jQuery = jQuery;
global.$ = jQuery;    

//https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2128
window.Date = Date;
```

Then you can use them as usual in your test scripts.